# Confused - why did my Windows 10 restart even though no update recorded?

Tags: windows-10, updates

I just witnessed some very strange behavior on my **Windows 10 Home** machine. I locked the laptop to go for dinner, and when I came back and unlocked it, it was obvious that Windows had restarted. Excel and Word opened up with recovery saves, some other programs were closed altogether, some programs that usually boot up together with the system were running despite I had closed them before.

I logged on at ~ 19:00 of 25/02. I locked the laptop 1-2 hours before, so the problem must have occurred in that time. Below some Event Viewer infos (system logs; I can also post application log if necessary):

```
Error   25/02/2018 19:13:01 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 19:08:15 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Information 25/02/2018 19:06:44 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Information 25/02/2018 19:04:22 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Warning 25/02/2018 19:01:42 Netwtw04    6105    None
Information 25/02/2018 19:01:02 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Warning 25/02/2018 19:00:53 Netwtw04    6105    None
Error   25/02/2018 19:00:11 DistributedCOM  10010   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:25 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:20 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:19 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:17 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:17 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:17 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:17 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:10 Kernel-General  16  None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:09 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:09 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:09 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:09 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:09 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:09 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:09 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:09 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:08 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:06 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:04 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:04 Kernel-General  16  None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:00 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:58:00 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:00 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:00 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:00 Kernel-General  15  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:58:00 Winlogon    7001    (1101)
Information 25/02/2018 18:09:56 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:07:53 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Error   25/02/2018 18:07:41 DistributedCOM  10010   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:46 TPM-WMI 1025    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:46 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:44 TPM-WMI 1025    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:42 TPM 18  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:41 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:41 Kernel-General  16  None
Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:41 WHEA-Logger 17  None
Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:41 WHEA-Logger 17  None
Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:41 WHEA-Logger 17  None
Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:41 WHEA-Logger 17  None
Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:41 WHEA-Logger 17  None
Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:41 WHEA-Logger 17  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:41 Service Control Manager 7026    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:40 WLAN-AutoConfig 4000    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Lfsvc   2   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 DHCPv6-Client   51046   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Dhcp-Client 50103   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Dhcp-Client 50036   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 EventLog    6013    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 EventLog    6009    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 EventLog    6005    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Directory-Services-SAM  16962   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:39 Wininit 14  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:38 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:37 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:37 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:37 BTHUSB  18  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:36 Kernel-General  15  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Ntfs (Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs)   98  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Power    521 (220)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 MEIx64  2   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Ntfs (Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs)   98  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Power    521 (220)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power)   55  (47)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power)   55  (47)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power)   55  (47)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power)   55  (47)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power)   55  (47)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power)   55  (47)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power)   55  (47)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-Processor-Power (Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power)   55  (47)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Netwtw04    7010    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Ntfs (Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs)   98  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Netwtw04    7001    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Netwtw04    7036    None
Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-PnP  219 (212)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:34 DriverFrameworks-UserMode   10118   Startup of the UMDF reflector
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 Kernel-Power    172 (203)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 Ntfs (Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs)   98  None
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:33 hpdskflt    1001    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:33 FilterManager   6   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:32 Kernel-Boot 30  (21)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:32 Kernel-Boot 32  (58)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:32 Kernel-Boot 18  (57)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:32 Kernel-Boot 25  (32)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:32 Kernel-Boot 27  (33)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:32 Kernel-Boot 20  (31)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:32 Kernel-Boot 153 (62)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:32 Kernel-General  12  (1)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:25 Kernel-General  13  (2)
Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:25 DNS Client Events   1014    (1014)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:23 Kernel-Power    109 (103)
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:18 WLAN-AutoConfig 4001    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:17 EventLog    6006    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:17 Dhcp-Client 50037   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:17 Dhcp-Client 50106   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:17 DHCPv6-Client   51057   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:17 DHCPv6-Client   51057   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:17 DHCPv6-Client   51047   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:17 Dhcp-Client 50105   Service State Event
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:17 Dhcp-Client 50104   Service State Event
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:15 DistributedCOM  10005   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:14 Service Control Manager 7023    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:13 Winlogon    7002    (1102)
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:13 DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:13 DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:13 DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:13 DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:13 DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   25/02/2018 18:05:13 DistributedCOM  10010   None
Information 25/02/2018 18:05:00 User32  1074    None
Information 25/02/2018 18:01:22 Kernel-General  1   (5)
Information 25/02/2018 18:01:22 Time-Service    35  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:01:18 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:01:07 Time-Service    37  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:01:06 Time-Service    158 None
Information 25/02/2018 18:01:01 Kernel-General  15  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:59 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:58 Kernel-General  15  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:57 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:57 Kernel-General  16  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:57 Kernel-General  15  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:50 Kernel-General  11  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:50 Kernel-General  11  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:50 Kernel-General  15  None
Information 25/02/2018 18:00:02 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Information 25/02/2018 17:57:37 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Information 25/02/2018 17:41:32 WindowsUpdateClient 19  Windows Update Agent
Information 25/02/2018 17:41:32 WindowsUpdateClient 43  Windows Update Agent
Information 25/02/2018 17:41:27 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Information 25/02/2018 17:41:27 UserPnp 20001   (7005)
Information 25/02/2018 17:41:27 Ntfs (Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs)   98  None
Error   25/02/2018 17:41:18 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Information 25/02/2018 17:33:01 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Information 25/02/2018 17:31:28 WindowsUpdateClient 44  Windows Update Agent
Error   25/02/2018 17:30:59 DistributedCOM  10016   None
Information 25/02/2018 17:28:02 UserPnp 20001   (7005)
Information 25/02/2018 17:28:02 UserPnp 20003   (7005)
Warning 25/02/2018 17:27:59 WHEA-Logger 17  None
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:57 Power-Troubleshooter    1   None
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:57 Service Control Manager 7040    None
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:55 Kernel-Boot 25  (32)
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:55 Kernel-Boot 27  (33)
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:55 Kernel-Boot 32  (58)
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:55 Kernel-Boot 18  (57)
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:55 Kernel-Boot 30  (21)
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:55 BTHUSB  18  None
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:54 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:54 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:54 UserModePowerService    12  (10)
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:54 EventLog    6013    None
Information 25/02/2018 17:27:53 Kernel-General  1   (5)
```

The weird thing is that in the Windows Update history, no system updates were intalled today. I have problems understanding what happened and would like to avoid that going forward. Any ideas what is off?

Comment: these look suspicious: `Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-PnP  219 (212) `and `Error   25/02/2018 18:05:33 hpdskflt    1001    None` and this one may tell you why there was a reboot: `Information 25/02/2018 18:05:00 User32  1074    None`

Comment: Also, there definitely are some Windows update activity going on: `Information 25/02/2018 17:41:32 WindowsUpdateClient 19  Windows Update Agent
Information 25/02/2018 17:41:32 WindowsUpdateClient 43  Windows Update Agent`

Comment: You can see what initiated the reboot by looking at the log messages just before shutdown. I’m currently not at a Windows machine, so I can’t provide further details, sorry. Also, don’t forget to look at the other logs (Application, Windows Update) for clues.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks! About `Information 25/02/2018 18:05:00 User32 1074 None`, `Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-PnP 219 (212)`, and `Error 25/02/2018 18:05:33 hpdskflt 1001 None` - any ideas what I could do to follow up and find out what is going on?

Comment: Also, please look into all those “WHEA” warning events. They’re not normal and could indicate hardware problems like overheating.

Comment: I now checked the details for `Information 25/02/2018 18:05:00 User32 1074 None` and it said: 

`The process c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe (LAPTOP-XX) has initiated the restart of computer LAPTOP-XX on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
 Reason Code: 0x80020010
 Shut-down Type: restart
 Comment:`

The strange thing is still that there is no update listed in the Windows Update history...

Comment: The installation of Feature updates are not recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look suspicious: `Warning 25/02/2018 18:05:34 Kernel-PnP 219 (212)` and `Error 25/02/2018 18:05:33 hpdskflt 1001 None` and this one may tell you why there was a reboot: `Information 25/02/2018 18:05:00 User32 1074 None`

Also, there definitely are some Windows update activity going on: `Information 25/02/2018 17:41:32 WindowsUpdateClient 19 Windows Update Agent Information 25/02/2018 17:41:32 WindowsUpdateClient 43 Windows Update Agent`

You checked the details for the User32 one which says:

> The process c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe (LAPTOP-XX) has initiated the restart of computer LAPTOP-XX on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned) Reason Code: 0x80020010 Shut-down Type: restart Comment: The strange thing is still that there is no update listed in the Windows Update history...

This clearly says that a Windows Update/feature pack installation is responsible for the reboot. Note, these feature pack installations do not always show up in the Windows Update settings tab.

Comment: Might be useful for the poster : https://www.askvg.com/fixing-windows-10-automatic-updates-install-problem/